# Как сделать БД со своим расширением в delphi?

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Долго искал,но ничего не удалось,объясню,мне для курсовой надо сделать программу которая работает с БД имеющее свое собственное расширение(например "baza.qz"),умоляю разъясните как мне это осуществить.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, мне кажется что вы допустили тут некоторую ошибку в суждениях. Услышав о СУБД вы сразу подумали о реляционной СУБД. Конечно-же мы все любим SQL, он велик, прекрасен и универсален, но для решения частной задачи он далеко не всегда является оптимальным инструментом. Конечно-же мы не знаем наверняка что за задача стоит перед @hj-81, но вполне возможно что для ней будет достаточно простейшей документ-ориентированной СУБД, реализуемой (в простейшем случае) через запись на диск сериализованной структуры данных.

Comment: @MrClon, автор не уточнил, какая БД ему нужна, поэтому я могу думать о чем угодно, хоть о реляционной бд, хоть о блокноте с ручкой. И ошибкой это не считаю.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, думать-то можно что угодно, свободу совести пока-что не отменили, но городить свою РСУБД их верёвочек и веточек идея по меньшей мере странная. Если задача хорошо ложится на реляционную модель данных, и нет причин желать чего-то странного, то будет более чем достаточно банального sqlite. Если sqlite по какой-то причине не подходит, то нужно идти от задач приложения, и скорее всего создание своего sqlite (с неблокирующими транзакциями и версионированием :) не будет оптимальным решением

Comment: @MrClon, ок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тут дело не столько в самой БД, сколько в СУБД. Вам нужно не просто продумать свой формат БД, но и организовать систему, которая сможет работать с этим форматом. Короче задача нетривиальная.

Для начала посмотрите в сторону xml, ну или попробуйте из ini файлов собрать что-то вроде таблиц... На ум так сразу ничего больше не приходит.

**UPD**
Еще можете обратиться к [стандартным средствам сериализации](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/delphi/serialization.xml).

Answer (score 3):

Расширение это просто окончание имени файла которое на самом деле ни на что не влияет. Так-что вы можете просто использовать любую встраиваемую базу данных (например sqlite) и хранить саму базу хоть в файле baza.qz, хоть в video.avi. Это всего-лишь названия.

Если нет нужды в реляционной базе данных, или если задание предполагает написание своей СУБД, то написать простенькую nosql СУБД достаточно просто. Возможно написание такой СУБД было-бы для вас ценным опытом (впрочем то-же можно сказать про использование sqlite, не городить велосипедов там где не надо — ценный навык).

Если решите идти по второму пути — рекомендую курс «[Базы данных](http://www.lektorium.tv/course/22977)» от Computer Science Center. Впрочем если решите по этому пути не идти, но планируете работать с базами данных — всё равно рекомендую этот курс.